# UITableView reloadData() gets fired but delays

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, reloaddata

I ran into this weird behavior of a `UITableView`.

I'm fetching some records from CloudKit in my app. I have set up a dedicated subclass of `NSObject` to handle all this, and anytime it receives a record, it adds the record to my model array and then tells its delegate it has received something. The delegate then reloads the `tableView`.

```
func cloudKitFetchedRecord(identifier: NSString) {
    if identifier.isEqualToString("getAllProfiles") {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This all works. Except for the fact that after i call `reloadData`, nothing happens for a while. It takes about 10-20 seconds for the table to actually reload. Weirdly, it also reloads when I tap the screen, but when I fire `reloadData` nothing happens.

I have checked my entire application, put in breakpoints everywhere, but the app isn't doing anything while it delays the reload. I also cleaned the project, cleaned the build folder, pretty much did everything I could come up with but it keeps doing this.

**Did anyone else run into this behavior, or does anyone know anything on how to solve it?**

Any comments would be highly appreciated

Comment: UIKit is not thread-safe, and your CloudKit's delegate message most probably arrives on a background thread.

Comment: Also, `identifier == "getAllProfiles"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `delegate` call happens in background, So all you need to do is to call `reloadData` function in **Main Thread**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.tableView.reloadData()})
```

Answer (score 6):

Run your reloadData method on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.tableView.reloadData()})
```